# Populate the lookup field using php tool kit[Salesforce]

Tags: integration, php

1) A lookup relation is defined between position and Candidate in SFDC

2) In HTML form, I am trying to send candidate information and position candidate has applied from PHP form to SFDC using PHP toolkit

3) Problem is when sending position as text and would like to somehow query or get the id of the position associated with this text before creating a candidate record (and associate candidate with this position) in sfdc

**HTML Form Code for the position field:**

```
<select name="position">     
     <option value="NONE">NONE</option>
     <option value="Driver">Driver</option>
    <option value="Technician">Technician</option>
    <option value="mechanic">mechanic</option>
    </select>
```

**Post(Using PHP Tool Kit)**

```
$fields = array ('Position__c'=>$_POST['position']);
```

Error:

```
Array ( [0] => Position__c ) [message] => Position: id value of incorrect type: Driver [statusCode] => MALFORMED_ID ) )
```

How can i solve this Error

Comment: what is the value of $_POST['position'] ?

Comment: it is the one of the pick-list values mentioned in the above code                           Example :Driver                                                             $_POST['position']='Driver' (The user will select this value in the form)

Comment: Can you post the exact value that was in the 'position' parameter when you got this error? My guess is that you did not have a valid 15 or 18 character Salesforce Id as the value.

Comment: how to get the salesforce id.I am passing the  pick-list value which is filled in the form directly to the post with the Variable name **position**                                                                                                                                                               I have put the "var_dump($fields);"                                                                  ["Position__c"]=> string(6) "Driver".

Comment: var_dump($fields);"                                                                                   ["Position__c"]=> string(6) "Driver". I am getting the string instead of the picklist value ID(Salesforce ID).How to get the id to pass to SFDC in the $_POST

Comment: There is no such thing as a picklist value id. If your target field is a lookup, it accepts the id of the record you are linking to. If your target field is a picklist it accepts a text value. When using a lookup you must first query for the possible record values from Salesforce, then set the field value to one of those ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Position is a lookup type field, you will need to send the Id of the record that you are populating in the field. For example, consider the scenario where you have a custom object named `Position_Type__c` with a record named `Driver`. If `Position__c` is a lookup to `Position_Type__c`, then sending the text `'Driver'` would result in an error because Salesforce is expecting the record Id not the record Name. The record Id will look something like `'00aEt0000001fjg'`. This makes your problem a bit more complicated because you will need to first query salesforce for the possible records before populating the options in your `<select>` list.

If possible, making `Position__c` a true picklist instead of a relationship in Salesforce will greatly simplify things for you because then you are setting pure text values like `'Driver'`.